# Cannot find module 'fs.realpath' after NPM v5.0.1 upgrade

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I recently updated npm to v5.0.1 (from the last version of 4), and it has been generally catastrophic.

Anyway, I'm stuck at this point.  Any node.js application I try to run completes an 'npm install' fine, but when started outputs:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fs.realpath'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/back/node_modules/glob/glob.js:44:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Note that this same application will run fine on macOs, but on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS it gives the above error.

I've removed the node_modules directory on both machines and re-run, macOs works fine, Ubuntu fails.

```
node -v: v6.10.3
```

...for both machines.

```
npm -v: 5.0.1
```

It also suggests I look at the log (`/home/user/.npm/_logs/2017-06-02T23_19_59_859Z-debug.log`), but it gives even less information.  Here's the error reported there:

```
13 info lifecycle back@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: back@0.0.1 start: `tsc && npm run moveassets && NODE_ENV=production forever start -a -l back.log -e back-err.log ./build/www.js `
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:283:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

Note that until the fateful upgrading of NPM to v5.0.1, it worked fine on both machines.

**UPDATE WITH PROBLEM ISOLATED:**

It seems it isn't the OS version, but the fact that macOS was generating the package-lock.json file and Ubuntu was consuming it and basing its install from it.  As noted below, if you remove the file and `rm -r node_modules` folder, you can install and it will all work fine (but you won't get the version locking benefits, obviously).

I think it is just a bug with the current version of NPM.  Fair enough, it was a big change and will be a good feature when done.

Comment: have you tried doing  a `npm cache clean`?

Comment: Heh - give that a run in NPM v5.0.1.  It will tell you that the cache is now perfect and you will never need to clean it again.  This, I have already seen, is not true.  You can still make it happen with `npm cache clean --force`, which does not help.

If you haven't upgraded to v5.0.1, I'd advise against it.  Check out the issue list on GitHub.  Its not great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

then do a

```
npm install
```

again, it works.

Note: I also removed the npm lock file.

**Update :**
(with taking comment in consideration)

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

Comment: By NPM lock file do you mean 'package-lock.json'?  If so, then yes, I have found that I can get past it by doing that as well.  That file is supposed to ensure a guarantee of version equivalence between the committing systems and the target systems (if I understand correctly), and clearly it is not doing it. I guess it is just a bug with NPM v5 at the moment.  It is a good idea for a feature so hopefully it gets worked out!

Comment: I think you should update your answer to state the specific file, but indeed this will get you past it!

Comment: I'll just add, for anyone reading this, that to this day on the latest NPM version I have never had npm install run correctly if the package-lock file is present.  I never check it in and I delete it before running any npm install operations.  Anytime npm is updated I try it again out of hope, and it always fails.  The irony is that it instructs you to check the file in, which will cause almost certain doom if your project isn't trivially simple.